# GeoServer filter function reference

Tags: geoserver, function

This Program/Project is working. Using the centroid function, I am able to filter the layer but I am confused about how to add another function where I can get the integer value from the column "active_cases".

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Pictures of code are not legible on all devices and would obligate each person who wanted to help to retype your code. Please post any code as text in the body of the question.

Comment: You seem to be working in the SLD editor but ask about Javascript - these are unrelated concepts so I think you need to [edit] your question to make it clear what you are actually trying to do.